# Handling regular jobs with possible manual start in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to solve a problem similar to downloading new mails from mail servers by mail client. I have a task, which is performed regularly (next iteration is 10 minutes after the last one ends for example) but there is also a possibility to run the task manually.

When I am trying to run the job manually and job is not running at this moment (is appointed for later), I cancel the appointment and schedule it for now. When the job is already running I do not cancel it, but wait until it finishes and run it again. But only one task can wait this way.

My problem is that I do not know how to synchronize the jobs to make it thread safe and make sure that job never runs twice at the same time.

To make it more clear. The main problem is that simple asking if the job is running and deciding based on what I get is not enough, because between the question and action the situation can change. It is a short span but the probability is not zero. And the same problem is with deciding if I should run the job again at the end of his run. If my decision is based on the value of some variable or some other if clause, then between testing its value and performing some action, some other thread can change it and I can end up with two scheduled jobs or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [DelayQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html)?

To make your job run `now` you just need to persuade it to return `0` form `getDelay(TimeUnit unit)`.

Comment: I do not understand how can this help. I can ask to get a  head of the queue, but in some cases I can get null, because the getDelay returns one millisecond and when I do a decision based on this it will break, because I will expect that it is not running and run it, causing that it will run twice.

Comment: You write your own [Delayed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html) and put it in the queue. You can then manipulate it externally to make it return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The main way to do that check you are telling about is to check, to lock and ***after that to repeat the same check***:

```
public class OneQueuedThread extends Thread {
    static int numberRunning =0;
    public void run() {
        if (numberRunning<2) {
            synchronized (OneQueuedThread.class){
                if (numberRunning<2) {
                    numberRunning++;
                    // ---------------your process runs here
                    numberRunning--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, only one attempt to run the thread while it is already running will wait until the end of the running thread and start after it.

As for scheduling, let's use the TimerTask features:

```
      public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
        ScheduledTask instance;


        /**
         * this constructor is to be used for manual launching
         */
        public void ScheduledTask(){
            if (instance == null){
                instance = this;
            } else {
                instance.cancel();
            }
            instance.run();
        }

        /**
         * This constructor is to be used for scheduled launching
         * @param deltaTime
         */
        public ScheduledTask(long deltaTime){
            instance = this;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(instance, deltaTime);

        }

        public void run() {
            OneQueuedThread currentTread;
            currentTread = new OneQueuedThread();
            currentTread.start();
        }
    }
```